# How can I access seperatly fields, the fields has same itemId?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have N number of Name & dept textfeilds like

```
0 +---Name----+ +----Dept----+
1 +---Name----+ +----Dept----+
2 +---Name----+ +----Dept----+
```

it'll be created `itemId:nameId` & `deptId` for all the rows.

I must be able to access both a particular name or dept textfield or all textfields in my controller.

Comment: Please be more clear for example what is the first name textfield's item ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access all textfields you can use this & iterate over it

```
var items = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + itemId);
for(var index in items){
    //Assuming that all name textfields start with name like name0, name1 etc
    if(items[index].indexOf("name") >=0){
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

You can use the same statement to get a single component

```
var item = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + itemId)[0];
```

Please note that itemId in this cause should be as unique as possible